# save only when data is changed jqgrid.saveRow

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am using inline edit and want to call `jqgrid.saveRow` (even if nothing changed). If the data is not changed then there must not be call to the server to update.

how to skip sending data to the server if during inline editing no data in the row are changed?

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear what you do. Do you want *to call `saveRow` manually*? You wrote: "want to call jqgrid.saveRow (even if nothing changed)", but in the title you wrote: "save only when data is changed jqgrid.saveRow". What is your problem? Do you want to send unchanged data to the server or not? Probably your question is: how to skip sending data to the server if during inline editing no data in the row are changed?

Comment: @Oleg : Yes that is what i meant!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jqGrid makes internally `jQuery.ajax` request to send the data to the server. You can use `ajaxRowOptions` option to make additional customization of the options used by `jQuery.ajax`. For example you can define `beforeSend` callback (see [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) of `jQuery.ajax` for details). The callback will be called *before* sending the data. It's important that one can cancel the ajax request by returning `false` from the callback. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11992420/315935) provide simple code which demonstrates how `beforeSend` callback can be defined.

To verify whether the data are changed or not during editing you can use internal jqGrid option `savedRow` (`.getGridParam("savedRow")` get the data). The option hold **array** of rows because jqGrid allows to call `editRow` for multipla strings at the same time. Every item of `savedRow` array have additional property `id` which you can use to find the item which will be currently saved.

So you can compare the data prepared to send to the server with the data saved in `savedRow`. You can do this inside of `beforeSend` callback. If you find out that the data are not changed the callback can return `false` to skip sending of the data to the server.